# rails advanced routing with module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, module, controller, routes

I have a rails app. Routing and folder structure is below. When I try to create `post_comment_reply` I get this error:

```
Started POST "/post_comments/114/post_comment_replies" for ::1 at 2016-03-21 
ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant Post::PostCommentRepliesController
```

It's weird that it's saying `Post::PostCommentRepliesController` instead of `Posts::PostCommentRepliesController`. My controller looks like `class Posts::PostCommentRepliesController < ApplicationController`

Can sby tell me why this is happening?

```
resources :posts do
  resources :post_comments, only: [:create, :update, :destroy], module: :posts
end

resources :post_comments, only: [] do 
  resources :post_comment_replies, only: [:create, :update, :destroy], module: :posts
end
```

controller folder structure:

```
controllers
  posts
    post_comments_controller.rb
    post_comment_replies_controller.rb
```

view folder structure

```
views
  posts
    post_comments
      ...html.erb
    post_comment_replies
      ...html.erb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is being resolved correctly, the problem is that it can't find the controller, mainly: Post::PostCommentRepliesController  as the error message states

Comment: Just added extra info. Can you check it out?

Comment: I had had a typo in the routes.rb eariler that got corrected but turns out I had to restart the server. I just don't know why since routes should be working without restart.

Comment: No, any change to routes requires a server restart in all versions of rails.  Anything that is modified in /config requires a server restart.